# Ethernet shield/WebServer problem: 'server is at 0.0.0.0'. Any suggestions how to debug it?

Tags: arduino-uno, ethernet, web-server

[image]

Ethernet shield problem. When running the WebServer example sketch, the Serial Monitor shows that `server is at 0.0.0.0`. Any suggestions how to debug it?

Answer (score 1):

That's what it's supposed to be. It's called INADDR_ANY. Read an introductory text on networks and you'll understand what that means.

If you try to connect to the IP address you specified, you'll see that you can indeed connect.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the case in my case :/

Answer (score 1):

The arduino only tells what it reads from the ethernet module and 0.0.0.0 is what you get when Arduino is not connected to it. It's a hardware problem, you either didn't connect the wires right or something's fried. I think it can also happen if your ethernet cable is unplugged.

This is absolutely not a sign that your module is accepting all connections. It would be the case if you set it that way but you are obviously expecting another ip adress. Someone should delete that answer.

Comment: If another answer is incorrect then it should be downvoted

Answer (score 1):

If possible, try running the same code on an identical Arduino. I had a similar issue, and it turned out one of my ICSP pins were burned.

Contrary to other answers here, the IP address will show the correct value in the Serial Monitor even though nobody is connected.